# How to access json data in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var newOptions = {
    "Option 1": "value1",
    "Option_2": ["value2","v1","v2","v3"],
    "Option 3": "value3"
};
```

I am new in jquery and json, And I don't know how to access or parse the data

Here in Option_2 there are multiple values and I want to split it and make a new dropdown menu which has values of Option 2 
and When i select option 3 other dropdown changes its options according to these keys.

PS: I have searched so many sites and Googled it hundreds of times but cant find the answer that is why I am asking this question.

I get reference from this Site https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/ 
and trying to make Dynamic dropdown using Json

Comment: You don't need to split the value as it's already an array. All you need is a loop.

Comment: `newOptions["Option_2"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$.each(newOptions.Option_2, function (index, elem) {
           alert(elem);
        });
```

Comment: Thanx for the help @Bharat now My another question is what if i have external json file Like data.json or something like that.. I tried by using `$.getJson(data.json,function(data{ .... }));`

Answer (score 0):

This is not JSON data, but to access them like this:

```
newOptions['Option 1'];
newOptions['Option_2'][0];
newOptions['Option_2'][1];
....
```

To fill them in a dropdown:

```
$.each(newOptions['Option_2'],function(item) {
   $('#idOfDropDown').append($('<option>', {value:item, text:item}));
   // Or simply the just use the next line:
   $('#idOfDropDown').append('<option val="'+item+'">'+item+'</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the json in the following way...

```
newOptions['Option 1'];
```